# How to upload multiple buffer objects to a same file in AWS S3 using node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload multiple buffer objects to a single file in aws s3. I am unable to do so.

For each of these buffers, I am able to upload them individually to a file in S3, but not combined.

```
let buffer: any = [];
let data: Buffer[] = [];
buffer[0] = await getModuleData("TK515184","companyProfileFull","bearer 1f96884e-8763-448b-9d07-bd4823e8e9b9","");
buffer[1] = await getModuleData("TK515184","fundingRound","bearer 1f96884e-8763-448b-9d07-bd4823e8e9b9","");
buffer[2] = await getModuleData("TK515184","acquisition","bearer 1f96884e-8763-448b-9d07-bd4823e8e9b9","");
buffer[3] = await getModuleData("TK515184","investment","bearer 1f96884e-8763-448b-9d07-bd4823e8e9b9","");
buffer[4] = await getModuleData("TK515184","fundamentals","bearer 1f96884e-8763-448b-9d07-bd4823e8e9b9","",["FY-1", "FY-0", "FQ-1", "FQ-0"],["FY+1", "FY+2", "FY+3", "FQ+1", "FQ+2", "FQ+3"]);
data[0] = await new OverviewModule().createTearSheetExcel(buffer[0]);
data[1] = await new AcquisitionModule().createAcquisitionExcel(buffer[2]);
data[2] = await new InvestmentModule().createInvestmentExcel(buffer[3]);
data[3] = await new FundingModule().createFundingExcel(buffer[1]);
data[4] = await new FAndE(["FY-1", "FY-0", "FQ-1", "FQ-0"],["FY+1", "FY+2", "FY+3", "FQ+1", "FQ+2", "FQ+3"]).createFundamentalsAndEstimatesExcel(buffer[4]);
for(let i = 0;i<5;i++)
{
    S3.upload(APP_BUCKET_NAME,"all.xlsx",data[i]);
}
```

"all.xlsx" => filename to be created and data=> array of buffers.

Comment: You can use the S3 Multipart API to upload chunks of one S3 object. Make a call at the end to combine the parts. It has been a while since I wrote code to implement this otherwise I would post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will help but the correct sdk of the `s3.upload()`  function is :

```
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Body: stream};
var options = {partSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, queueSize: 1};
s3.upload(params, options, function(err, data) {
  console.log(err, data);
});
```

with the options parameter not to be mandatory.

Now for multiple uploads the logic is to make a for - loop for all your buffer objects and use the upload() in each of them.

Comment: I have updated my logic as per your comment. Now the problem is only one of the buffers in showing in the file created by S3.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot upload an array of buffers to S3: if your goal is that the file `all.xslx` in S3 contains your series of buffers concatenated together, you need to concatenate the buffers together first, and then upload the single buffer.

```
let combinedBuffer = buffer[0].concat(buffer.slice(1));

// Now upload combinedBuffer to S3
```

That said, I'm not sure if that's what you really want - this is going to produce a single file that contains a bunch of back-to-back Excel files, not (for example) a single Excel file with multiple sheets, which you would have to build yourself. (Not an expert, perhaps Excel is smart enough to open such a file anyway, not sure.)